# Update scikit model so it is compatible with newest version

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, compatibility, joblib

I have a question about scikit models and (retro-)compatibility.

I have a model (saved using joblib) created in Python 3.5 from scikit-learn 0.21.2, which I then analyze with the package shap version 0.30. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 I have Python 3.8 (and newer versions of both scikit-learn and shap).
Because of the new packages version I cannot load them with Python 3.8, so I make a virtual environment with Py3.5 and the original package versions.

Now my question is: is there a way to re-dump with joblib the models so I can also open them with Python 3.8? I'd like to re-analyze the model with the newest version of the package shap (but of course it has a scikit version requirement that would break the joblib loading).

Alternatively, what other options do I have? (The only thing I do not want is to re-train the model).

Comment: There is nothing out-of-the-box. If your model is supported, you can try [this](https://github.com/mlrequest/sklearn-json).

Comment: I am fine with not ready-made solutions or workarounds. I tested your suggestion and worked well for one model (a random forest model which is supported). For another object (not from sk-learn) I am still in troubles. 
But it worked perfectly code-wise (saved as json in sk-learn 0.21 and reloaded in 0.24).  I still have to test the prediction. 
Anyway if you answer I will accept it, as it is essentially one very valid and easy workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no standard solutions within scikit-learn. If your model is supported, you can try [sklearn-json](https://github.com/mlrequest/sklearn-json).

Although this does not solve your current issue, you can in the future save your models in formats with fewer compatibility issues – see the [Interoperable formats](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#interoperable-formats) section in scikit-learn's Model persistence page.

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

- load the old version and then serialize it in a more interoperable format that doesn't suffer from the version requirements of pickle:
  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#interoperable-formats
- retrain the model using original data with the new library version
- manually transfer weights and all prameters to new model instance (inspect old object for all paramaters and copy them to a new object with the new library/python version) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77657267/21040193